# How to show Google Spreadsheet changes without reloading page?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a use case in my application to export data to a SpreadSheet.

For context, the use case is:

- The user accesses the application (Front) using their web browser.
- The user clicks on the button to export data.
- At this time, a request is sent to an API rest (back application) to start the export.
- The **Back application creates a spreadsheet** and returns the ID.
- The Front application opens the spreadsheet in a new tab.
- The **Back application adds data asynchronously (using the GDrive rest API)** to the spreadsheet.

At this point, user need to reload the page multiple times to see the changes that the back application is making on the spreadsheet. Is there any way to see the changes without having to reload the page?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I already posted an answer. If you need something more specific, please [edit] your question to add more details about what is done by the "GDrive rest API" (try to add a [mcve])

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Google Drive API try using the Google Sheets API, if that doesn't work as you need, you should consider to completely change how your solution works in order to achieve what you are looking for by using Google Apps Script.

NOTE:

Please bear in mind that

1. if your spreadsheet has formulas they are recalculated on the client side every time that an change is made to the spreadsheet
2. the spreadsheet recalculation is proportional to the number and complexity of the formulas.
3. Some changes to the spreadsheet, i.e. changing the spreadsheet timezone, will cause an automatic spreadsheet reloading.

Comment: Hello, I have used the sheets API but the changes are not visible until the user reloads the page.

Comment: Hi,

it seems the problem is with the specific spreadsheet.

There is something in the spreadsheet that prevents changes from being viewed.

I have made a request for a different spreadsheet and the changes are displayed correctly (Using the Google APIs browser). Could it be some configuration parameter of the spreedsheet? Could it be some parameter at the time the spreadsheet is created?

Comment: I have found the problem. Basically the problem occurs when the number of rows added for the first time (first load of the spreadsheet in the browser) is greater than the initialized rows in the spreadsheet. If the sreadsheet is initialized with enough rows, the changes are displayed correctly. The funny thing is that if new data is added later and the number of rows is exceeded, they are added without problem and displayed correctly